# How do I XOR a block of bytes read from a binary file in Python?

Tags: python, file, byte, xor

I am reading a block of bytes from a binary file using file.read(block_size). The variable that these bytes go into is typed <class 'bytes'>.

I need to XOR each byte in the stream with single byte value expressed in Hex, e.g. \x0A.

What is the operator in Python for doing this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html

Answer (score 0):

Python's bitwise-XOR operator is `^`

```py
>>> 15^8
7
```

edit:
The XOR operator works with hex numbers as well:

```
>>> 0xA^8
2
```